# Passing 'this' to prototype function nested function

Tags: javascript, this, prototype

what's the best style to pass 'this.dayNames' and use it within the nested function (createCalendar())?

```
function DateNames()
{
    this.dayNames = ["Su", "M", "T", "W", "Th", "F", "S"];
}

DateNames.prototype.render = function(date)
{
    console.log(date);
    createCalendar()
    function createCalendar()
    {
        console.log(this.dayNames);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider removing the inner function? It's not being called and it changes the `this` binding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work, and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work-and-when-should-it-be-used)

Comment: @evolutionxbox, forgot to add that it was actually being called.

Comment: Consider removing `createCalendar` or using an arrow function instead